Can I use PNPM with AWS SAM
I'm trying to use PNPM with AWS SAM, but there seems to be no documentation on using PNPM. I know when using SLS you can work with YARN but I'm unsure of PNPM with AWS SAM. If anyone can point in the right direction. that'd be great.
I tried PNPM install and that works but doing SAM DEPLOY runs into issues and code will sometimes outright not work.
